# How to Properly create Install Shield Setup in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, setup-project, setup-deployment

Seems like a simple question but I am facing some weird problems.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, Enterprise Edition and Install Shield to create setup of my software, this is my first time making a general purpose software. Everything goes according to plan but I get these 2 problems.

Problems are:

1. Shortcuts don't work
2. Application doesn't launch until I run from root directory as admin

Problem 1:
I create the setup and do everything asked, I put the primary output into setup, which by the way contains 2 files. the `.exe` file and a `.config` file and I choose the primary output in "*add*" button to create a shortcut but when I install that setup, the Desktop shortcut doesn't work, in no way.

Problem 2:When I simply double click on the software's main `.exe` file, it doesn't run. No response but when I run it as Admin, it responses and opens. The problem is weird cause this doesn't happen in debug or the release files of the software.

Is there something I am doing wrong? maybe the way I insert the primary output?

Comment: If I didn't made myself clear, let me know where I can provide more info :)

Comment: Edit the question to include more info.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be an installation problem. Your statement "..when I run it as Admin, it responses and opens" means that your program requires admin privilegs to run correctly, and running it from a shortcut does not automatically run it as administrator. The usual way to say that a program needs elevation when it runs is to give it an elevation manifest as here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

with requireAdministrator. The program will then show the standard dialog requesting elevation.

The most likely reason for your program doing nothing when it fails is that it silently crashes and goes away, and that's probably because your code isn't explicitly making sure that everything you do is actually working. For example, if you try to create/modify a file in Program Files (and you're not elevated) it will fail, and your code should check that access was denied.